# Is strcmp(p, "\n") undefined behavior when p points to a character?

Tags: c, string, pointers, c99, undefined-behavior

Check the min ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char newline = '\n';
    char* p = &newline;
    if(strcmp(p, "\n") == 0) {
        printf("ok\n");
    } else {
        printf("wrong\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it undefined behaviour? Or is it simply wrong (i.e. it will always return not equal)? Whatever it is, please explain why!

Comment: [What should I do when OP ask me to delete my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258745/583833)

Comment: @Borgleader your link convinced me. Even though I am ashamed for my question I will accept the best answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's undefined, so all bets are off, but unless you have a very exotic C implementation, the result probably depends on whatever happens to follow the char in memory.

You can do what you want like this:

```
strncmp(p, "\n", 1) == 0
```

Or, indeed, like this:

```
p[0] == '\n'
```

Comment: I saw the comment, I think this is a very very poor question, thus it should be deleted. Can you delete your answer please, so that I can delete it?

Comment: How is it a poor question? It's clear, it comes with an example, and the answer may help others.

Comment: Well, it was trivial, but I failed to see the answer simply because I had too much time to write C. You can see it in the -2 score too. Don't you agree?

Comment: @chux that's true, but not relevant enough to confuse newbies.

Comment: @chux happy now? I'm not sure it's clearer, but it says what I meant without hiding anything.

Answer (score 5):

It's UB for the simple reason that `p` is not a null-terminated string, and `strcmp` is UB if input a non null-terminated string.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will be undefined.

`strcmp` requires two sequences of characters; each *terminated* with `\0`.

`p` does not satisfy that. `"\n"` does.

Comment: Thanks! Does `nullptr` exist in C?

Comment: No such thing as `nullptr` in C. The terminating character is an ASCII `NUL` (not to be confused with the `NULL` macro).

Comment: Oops. Need to stop programming in C++ for a while. And, absolutely, @Jens makes the very important distinction between NUL and NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `strcmp(p1,p2)` is only defined in the situation where p1 identifies the start of a range of accessible memory containing a zero byte, and p2 does likewise.  The behavior of

```
int foo(int bar)
{
  char b=bar;
  return strcmp(&b, "Moo");
}
```

would be fully defined in the situation where 'bar' is zero (a null string
would be required to compare less than a non-null string literal) but
undefined in all other cases.  If the code had been:

```
int foo(int bar, int boz)
{
  char arr[2];
  arr[0] = bar; arr[1] = boz;
  return strcmp(arr, "Moo");
}
```

then behavior would be defined in all cases where either bar or boz is zero,
but not in cases where both hold non-zero values.

Comment: @gsamaras: That better?